# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - server's temporary file storage

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

While reading docs, I came across following:

> When LOCAL is used, the client program reads the file and sends its
> contents to the server. The server creates a copy of the file in the
> directory where it stores temporary files. [See Section B.3.3.5, “Where
> MySQL Stores Temporary Files”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-files.html). Lack of sufficient space for the copy
> in this directory can cause the LOAD DATA LOCAL statement to fail.

I am using AWS RDS MySQL v8.0.28.

I have following 3 questions:

1. Does MySQL server automatically cleans up the temp file storage without a reboot?
2. How to find out how much temp file storage is allocated to my instance of database?
3. How can I increase this temp file storage on AWS RDS instance?

Comment: #1 - Yes. #2 and #3 - ask your hoster.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for reply. For #1, does the cleanup happen after every "load data local infile" completion?

Comment: *For #1, does the cleanup happen after every "load data local infile" completion?* Tempfile removing is a step of LOAD DATA execution, and it does not depend on the loading result. Of course, if server hangs/fails then tempfile won't be removed.

Comment: On Linux(etc), a reboot clears all of "/tmp".  However, MySQL may or may not be using that directory for "temp" stuff; see `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`  That is, MySQL's tmpdir may or may not be cleared even on a reboot.  (All of this is mostly irrelevant to the _real_ question.)